# MySQL - grab data from yesterday if past midnight

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got a database that contains the **daily dish**, **opening time** and **closing time**.
What I'm looking for is a way to check if the time is within these times, for example:
**Opening time:** 14:00
**Closing time:** 02:00 *<-- (Pay attention to this, it's past 00:00)*

If the times could just be from 00:00 to 23:59, this problem would be super easy to solve (I would just check if the current time for the current day is within these times).
But that is not the case, because the day has changed, so the times from yesterday wont be checked, meaning the restaurant that closed at 02:00 will not be returned.

Here is how I declare the names of the days opening/closing time in PHP, for the query:

```
$day_open = array('d1_o', 'd2_o', 'd3_o', 'd4_o', 'd5_o', 'd6_o', 'd7_o');
$day_close = array('d1_c', 'd2_c', 'd3_c', 'd4_c', 'd5_c', 'd6_c', 'd7_c');

// This is the name of the week days dishes
$dish_dd_array = array('d1_t', 'd2_t', 'd3_t', 'd4_t', 'd5_t', 'd6_t', 'd7_t');

$weekday = date('N'); // This returns 1 for monday, 5 for friday etc..
$current_time = date("H:i", time()); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT {$dish_dd_array[$weekday-1]} FROM restaurants WHERE (({$day_open[$weekday-1]} < {$day_close[$weekday-1]} AND '{$current_time}' BETWEEN {$day_open[$weekday-1]} AND {$day_close[$weekday-1]}) OR ".
    "({$day_open[$weekday-1]} > {$day_close[$weekday-1]} AND ('{$current_time}' > {$day_open[$weekday-1]} OR '{$current_time}' < {$day_close[$weekday-1]})))");
```

The query is kind of long so I will explain it here aswell:
It just checks if the current time is within the current days opening/closing time in the database. If it is, it will then return the dish.

Just to clarify, this code works flawlessly if the time range is within 00:00 and 23:59 for the same day, but I want to support even times efter 24:00 so night restaurants can be visible too!

*Thanks in advance,

Tompa*

Comment: Is there a restaurant that opens at midnight?

Comment: Yes, but that would not cause any problems since it's all on the same day

Answer (score 0):

What I did here is add a condition if the closing time is

> **AM** or **PM**

If it is AM the closing is that time the next day . When PM consider it as the same day. It is very **RARE** to have a closing time in AM at the same day.

Or **ELSE** you should add a **FLAG** ( a column on your database with true or false value or on your settings file ) to determine if the closing time is on the same or next day.

Comment: it isn't rare to have shifts that span midnight

Comment: We are talking about the opening and closing of the store. It is very rare to have like opening of store at 12am and closing it to 11:59am.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that midnight is an arbitrary distinction for the benefit of us mere humans. There is no such thing as midnight in a time interval. So if the time we are looking at is at or after the opening time on Monday and before the opening time on Tuesday, we can safely assume it was during the Monday business hours. You don't even need the closing time.

```
WHERE   '{$current_time}' >= {$day_open[$weekday-1]} 
    AND '{$current_time}' < {$day_open[$weekday]})
```